# PERMISSION_DENIED while decrypt PlayIntegrity token at backend

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-cloud-console, google-play-integrity-api

I am getting following error code and message while decrypting a PlayIntegrity token in Java. Could you please help me out why this issue occurs although we have given required API enabled and permissions.

```json
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "You are not authorized to decode the requested integrity token.",
      "reason": "forbidden"
    }
  ],
  "message": "You are not authorized to decode the requested integrity token.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: I have removed the _"Hope that you will reverted ASAP, as we have to deliver this feature."_ from your question as we're not Google support. You also need to provide more information, including a [mre].

Comment: I understand your concern about the given question. But I didn't find any related question from stackoverflow questions list yet. I just need help where we have missed any steps or permission. Anyway I have asked the same to google support.

Comment: Team, we got the root cause of this issue, which is that we missed access to the Service Usage Consumer in service account as outlined in the documentation.: https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#decrypt-verify-google-servers.  Thanks & Regards,